# Generalization of the Hessian to field theory

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, variational-principle

For the Ostrogradski theorem to apply, in classical mechanics (finite number of degrees of freedom) the Lagrangian needs to be non-degenerate. This means that the Hessian matrix (second derivatives of $L$ with respect to the highest order derivatives of each of the fields), has maximum rank. For a theory like $L(q,\dot{q},\ddot{q},n,\dot{n})$,
$$ Hess(L)(t)=\begin{pmatrix}\dfrac{\partial^{2}L}{\partial\ddot{q}^{2}} & \dfrac{\partial^{2}L}{\partial\ddot{q}\partial\dot{n}}\\
\dfrac{\partial^{2}L}{\partial\dot{n}\partial\ddot{q}} & \dfrac{\partial^{2}L}{\partial\dot{n}^{2}}
\end{pmatrix}.$$

**Question**. How is this notion generalized to field theory? For example, to a theory of the type
$$L[\phi,\dot{\phi},\ddot{\phi},\psi,\dot{\psi}]=\int d^{n-1} x \ \mathcal{L}(\phi,\dot{\phi},\ddot{\phi},\psi,\dot{\psi},\text{spatial derivatives of arbitrary order})$$
(the dots mean $\partial_0$).

Do you know of any good reference in which this is explained? (the notes I have seen basically explain the idea in the context of a finite number of degrees of freedom, but not the generalization to fields).

---

Guess:

Inspired by the idea that ''the Hessian in the usual physical cases essentially coincides with the kinetic matrix'', e.g. for a field theory of the type given above, my guess would be to compute first the matrix of second variations:
$$ M=\begin{pmatrix}\dfrac{\delta^{2}L}{\delta\ddot{\phi}^{2}} & \dfrac{\delta^{2}L}{\delta\ddot{\phi}\delta\dot{\psi}}\\
\dfrac{\delta^{2}L}{\delta\dot{\psi}\delta\ddot{\phi}} & \dfrac{\delta^{2}L}{\delta\dot{\psi}^{2}}
\end{pmatrix}.$$

This is not what I would called the Hessian, since it has a distributional nature. Indeed, to be more precise I should write
$$ M(\vec{x},\vec{y},t)=\begin{pmatrix}\dfrac{\delta^{2}L}{\delta\ddot{\phi}(\vec{x},t)\delta\ddot{\phi}(\vec{y},t)} & \dfrac{\delta^{2}L}{\delta\ddot{\phi}(\vec{x},t)\delta\dot{\psi}(\vec{y},t)}\\
\dfrac{\delta^{2}L}{\delta\dot{\psi}(\vec{x},t)\delta\ddot{\phi}(\vec{y},t)} & \dfrac{\delta^{2}L}{\delta\dot{\psi}(\vec{x},t)\delta\dot{\psi}(\vec{y},t)}
\end{pmatrix}$$
(defined at a fixed time $t$). One could multiply by a test function and eliminate one of the coordinates, and the result seems to be a reasonable definition for the Hessian in a field theoretical context:
$$ (Hess(L)(\vec{x},t))f(\vec{x}):=\int d^{n-1}y M(\vec{x},\vec{y},t)f(\vec{y}).$$

Comment: I don't know of any reference which treats this in details, but your guess seems correct. Also, note that $L$ is the integral of a local lagrangian density, $M(\vec x,\vec y,t)$ is equal to $\delta^{(3)}(\vec x-\vec y)$ times the matrix with the relevant second partial derivatives of $\mathcal L$.

Comment: Yes! @SolubleFish Indeed, that's correct in many cases, but there are others in which $M$ can be an operator matrix. For instance, in the theory $\mathcal{L}= \partial_i \dot{\phi} \partial^i\dot{\phi}$, the Hessian will be essentially the Laplacian $\Delta$.